# How to stream audio to my PC from my phone without AUX cable?

Tags: audio

I'm trying to use my phone as a soundboard, but i need it to play the sound in my PC when i press a button on my phone

I was wondering if there is a way to do that with USB as i dont have a AUX cable

Comment: Sounds like a case for [DLNA / uPnP Server and Clients](https://android.izzysoft.de/catmin/applists/category/named/multimedia_dlna), with your phone as server & control point and your PC as client.

Answer (score 0):

With this app (Weezzler) you can easily play audio from your phone in your browser as long as you are connected to the same wifi network in the device and the computer.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.weezzler.android